# how to install ssl on tomcat 7?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, tomcat7, keytool

I know this question might sound too easy and I should had read all docs available on internet, the true is that I did, and I had no luck, its kinda confusing for me, I have installed many times this thing but for Apache, never for Tomcat.

I want to install a certificate from GoDaddy, so, I followed this instructions

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5239/generating-a-csr-and-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat-4x5x6x

I created my keyfile like this

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file csr.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

I changed tomcat for mydomain.com .. is it wrong?

I created the keystore, later the csr, after that the problem comes, I add to server.xml on the config folder

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200"
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="path to your keystore file" keystorePass="changeit" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Later I imported the certs

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file valicert_class2_root.crt
```

and I did, but I dont have a gd_intermediate.crt and the last step is

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file <name of your certificate>
```

reading in other blogs I saw they import here the crt , but tomcat is the user I have to leave? or its for example only??

In the docs of tomcat I found this
(http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

> Download a Chain Certificate from the Certificate Authority you
>   obtained the Certificate       keytool -import -alias root -keystore
>    \
>       -trustcacerts -file
>
> ```
>    And finally import your new Certificate
>        keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore <your_keystore_filename> \
> -file <your_certificate_filename>
> ```

but I have no idea what is a "chain certificate" ... can somebody help me? I am really confused and lost. I am using Tomcat7

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is more like a workaround, but as you have experience with setting up SSL on Apache, you could consider serving your Tomcat webapp through Apache (as a reverse proxy), and Apache should be able to encrypt at that level.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to clarify a bit the signing procedure:

- Key generation: you create a private key
- CSR generation: with your private key you create a request to a Certification Autority that contains a cert to be signed
- CA signature: CA signs your certificate and send it back to you (it now has inside your fingerprint and ca one).
- cert import: import signed cert in keystore thus making it available to tomcat
- chain-cert import: import certs that defines the trust-chain

CA can delegate signing so in order to be sure that a signed cert is valid, clients should be able to check every CA identity. (i.e your cert is signed by ca.contoso and contoso uses verisign as cert authority; client will check then contoso and then verisign one, if all are OK your cert is considered valid)

Answer (score 0):

I spend hours trying to figure this out and here are the fruits of my labor

## Problem

You are unable to create a valid Tomcat Keystore using a GoDaddy crt and key file

Curl output may look like this:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

## Getting the Script

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/ssstonebraker/braker-scripts/master/working-scripts/crt_to_keystore.sh
chmod +x crt_to_keystore.sh
```

## Using the script

```
./crt_to_keystore.sh <path_to_crt> <path_to_key>
```

## RAW Contents of Script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Filename: crt_to_keystore.sh
# Description: create tomcat keystore from cert and key
# Usage: "Usage: ./crt_to_keystore.sh <path_to_crt> <path_to_key>"
# Author: Steve Stonebraker
# pretty printing functions
function print_status { echo -e "\x1B[01;34m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function print_good { echo -e "\x1B[01;32m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function print_error { echo -e "\x1B[01;31m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function print_notification { echo -e "\x1B[01;33m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function printline { hr=-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
printf '%s\n' "${hr:0:${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}}"
}
####################################
# print message and exit program
function die { print_error "$1" >&2;exit 1; }
####################################
# function that is called when the script exits
function finish {
    [ -f $(dirname $0)/temp.p12 ] && shred -u $(dirname $0)/temp.p12;
}

#whenver the script exits call the function "finish"
trap finish EXIT
#######################################
# if file exists remove it
function move_file_if_exist {
  [ -e $1 ] && mv $1 $1.old && print_status "moved file $1 to $1.old";
}
#######################################
# Verify user provided valid file
function file_must_exist {
  [ ! -f $1 ] && die "$1 is not a valid file, please provide a valid file name!  Exiting....";
  print_status "$1 is a valid file"
}
#######################################
# Verify user provided two arguments
# Verify user provided two arguments
[ $# -ne 2 ] && die "Usage: ./crt_to_keystore.sh <path_to_crt> <path_to_key>";

# Assign user's provided input to variables
crt=$1
key=$2
#read -p "Provide password to export .crt and .key: " key_pw
read -p "Provide password for new keystore: " pw

# Define some Variables
readonly ourPath="$(dirname $0)"
readonly gdbundle="$ourPath/gd_bundle.crt"  
readonly keystore="$ourPath/tomcat.keystore"
readonly p12="$ourPath/temp.p12"
readonly KEYTOOL=$(which keytool)
readonly OPENSSL=$(which openssl)

#######################################
# Functions used by main execution
function gd_check_cert {
    # Verify gd_bundle.crt exists
    [ ! -f "$1" ] && print_error "$1 not found!  Downloading..." && wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/$1;
    [ ! -f "$1" ] && die "$1 must exist in current path!  Exiting....";
    [ -f "$1" ] && print_status "found $1 in current path"
}

function verify_before_execution {
    printline
    #verify godaddy cert
    gd_check_cert $gdbundle

    #Check to make sure the user provided valid files

    file_must_exist ${crt}
    file_must_exist ${key}

    move_file_if_exist ${keystore}
}

function import_godaddy_root {
    print_status "Importing gd_bundle.crt to java key store..."

    ${KEYTOOL} -import \
    -alias root \
    -keystore ${keystore} \
    -trustcacerts \
    -file ${gdbundle} \
    -keypass ${pw} \
    -storepass ${pw}  >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    [ ! $? -eq 0 ] && die "Error running command... Exiting!";
}

function export_to_p12 {
    printline
    print_status "Exporting your key and cert to pkcs12 format..."
    ${OPENSSL} pkcs12 -export -chain -CAfile gd_bundle.crt -inkey ${key} -in ${crt} -out ${p12} -password pass:${pw}

    [ ! $? -eq 0 ] && die "Error running command... Exiting!";

}

function import_p12_file {
    print_status "Importing p12 file to java key store..."
    ${KEYTOOL} -importkeystore \
    -srcalias 1 \
    -destalias tomcat \
    -srckeystore ${p12} \
    -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
    -srcstorepass ${pw} \
    -destkeystore ${keystore} \
    -keypass ${pw} \
    -storepass ${pw} \
    -dest‐storepass ${pw} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    [ ! $? -eq 0 ] && die "Error running command... Exiting!";
}

function print_msg_after_creation {
    printline
    print_good "Keystore ${keystore} creation complete!"
    printline
    print_status "Don't forget to copy ${keystore} to /etc/tomcat7/tomcat.keystore and update server.xml"
    printline
}

#######################################
# Main Execution
verify_before_execution
export_to_p12
import_godaddy_root
import_p12_file
print_msg_after_creation
```

Source: http://brakertech.com/convert-valid-godaddy-cert-key-to-java-keystore/